# Mass matrix and BDF time integration

Tags: computational-physics, numerics, implicit-methods

I have a system of nonlinear equations on the general form:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{M}(\bar{y})\dot{\bar{y}} =\bar{f}(\bar{y},t)
\end{align}
Where $\mathbf{M}(\bar{y})$ is a matrix and $\bar{f}$ is a system of non-linear functions acting on $\bar{y}$. This system has many stiff elements and so i wish to solve it using the implicit BDF method with newton iterations for solving the non-linear system.

My question is then related to how to treat the mass matrix in the BDF method when it depends on $\bar{y}$. When reading about the method in textbooks or e.g. wikipedia, the method is stated as:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{s}\alpha_k\bar{y}_{n-k} = h\bar{f}(\bar{y}_{n},t_{n})
\end{align}
But if a mass matrix is included, should it be treated as the lhs or rhs? I.e.
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{s}\alpha_k\mathbf{M}(\bar{y}_{n-k})\bar{y}_{n-k} = h\bar{f}(\bar{y}_{n},t_{n})
\end{align}
Or
\begin{align}
\mathbf{M}(\bar{y}_{n})\sum_{k=0}^{s}\alpha_k\bar{y}_{n-k} = h\bar{f}(\bar{y}_{n},t_{n})
\end{align}
I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: If you multiply the equation by $M^{-1}$ (even if only formally), then the first equation you have is in the standard form in which ODEs are usually stated. Then apply the BDF method to get the time-discrete form. If possibly, you can then multiply by $M$ again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second one is the correct form. BDF approximates derivative with backward difference.

Write
$$
M(y) \dot{y} = f(y,t)
$$
as
$$
\dot{y} = M^{-1}(y) f(y,t) =: F(y,t)
$$
write the BDF for this
$$
\sum_{k=0}^s \alpha_k y_{n-k} = h F(y_n,t) = h M^{-1}(y_n) f(y_n,t_n)
$$
Hence you get
$$
M(y_n) \sum_{k=0}^s \alpha_k y_{n-k} = h f(y_n,t_n)
$$